# OutlookServicesClient SendMailAsync does not call accessTokenGetter

Tags: wcf, office365, swagger

Because it does not call the method it fails with "unauthorized".  My workaround is to create a draft mail using AddMessageAsync which does call the accessTokenGetter and then SendAsync.

Question 1 - Where is the source for this library, it does not appear to be opensource

Question 2 - I'd like to create a wcf data service client instead of this but I'm not sure how as I cant create the service ref by using Add Reference as it requires an Azure AD token.

I'd like to use the Create Rest API Client in the Azure AD but I need a swagger URL for Office 365

Comment: Why you you think that Office 365 uses Swagger? I know it did a couple years ago, but I think that's been discontinued for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

> > Question 1 - Where is the source for this library, it does not appear to be opensource

This library is not open source however it was not confused or encrypted. You can use third-party tools like ILSpy to reflect the code.

> > Question 2 - I'd like to create a wcf data service client instead of this but I'm not sure how as I cant create the service ref by using Add Reference as it requires an Azure AD token.

At present, there are two possible authentication for the  Mail REST API. One is using the Office 365 authentication which already be support formally(need Office 365 subscription). Here is the helpful link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog#Outlookmail

The other way is using the new authentication model called v2.0 which is in preview. And this model support both Office 365 work or school account, or a Microsoft account. Here is the helpful link:

https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted

The REST API supports multiple authentication protocol using Microsoft Azure Active Directory like(OAuth 2.0, OpenID Connect 1.0, SAML Protocol, WS-Federation 1.2).
If we using OAuth 2.0, we need to provide the access token when we call the REST API. And Microsoft also provide some library to help developer developing like Azure Active Directory Authentication Libraries.

Here is some helpful links about the authentication about the Azure AD using by Office 365 REST API:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-libraries/

Microsoft also provide lots of code samples to help developers to get start:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/starter-projects-and-code-samples

However, I am not able to understand that "need a swagger URL for Office 365". For some authentication workflow, there is "redirect_uri" which will indicate the Microsoft Azure AD to redirect after the request has been authenticated.